# Simple Word Game Loop

Tags: ruby, loops

```
# Guessing Game
# 1.0
# by Proto


words = ["cat", "snake", "wolf", "giraffe", "elephant"]

picked = words.sample

puts "Welcome to the guessing game! I'm thinking of an animal. 
It's a #{picked.length} letter word. Can you guess what it is?"

try = gets.chomp

while try != picked 
    puts "Try again."
    try = gets.chomp
    if try == picked
        puts "You win!"
        break
    end
end
```

It works but only sometimes and I get no errors from running it. The problem is that if I get the guess right on the first try, the game doesn't seem to enter the loop at all (it doesn't tell me "You win!"), it just exits the program. But that result is inconsistent. If i immediately restart and get it right sometimes it will tell me that I won. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. There seems to be something wrong with my loop or syntax, but I can't see it. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider writing this as `loop do; try = gets.chomp; if try == picked; puts "You win!"; break; else; puts "Try again."; end; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `if` block and put the `"You win!"` statement outside the `while` statement. Reason being, eventually, in your current logic the player will win, and only then the logic breaks, so you might as well move it out.

```
while try != picked 
    puts "Try again."
    try = gets.chomp
end

puts "You win!"
```

The reason the `"You win!"` is not printed in your existing code is that the loop is never entered when `try == picked` initially, because that is the condition in the `while` loop.
The above changes take care of that scenario as well.

Comment: I swear I knew the solution would be so obvious. That makes sense. Initially I tried writing this in different ways. At first I put the win statement alone above the while loop, thinking the loop isn't invoked when the player wins on the first try. But that didn't fix it so I put it back inside the loop.So then I reversed the loop to check for a win condition first and only invoke the lose condition after checking. That didn't fix it either. Seeing this makes perfect sense. OF COURSE I don't even need an if statement for the win condition *because of* the loop. Tyvm for the explanation.